# Jquery codes does not work on external loaded html file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have index.php and will load index-edit.php with a button click into index.php in a `<div class="edit-wrapper"> </div>`. I have some input in index.php and some input in index-edit.php. I want to add `.active` class to them on focus out, but jQuery does not add `.active` class to the ones in index-edit.php, but rest of them (which are not index-edit.php) works fine.

Look at my script.js.

```
$( input ).focusout( function() {
    $( this ).addClass('active');
});

$( document ).on( "click", ".btn", function() {
    $('.edit-wrapper').load('index-edit.php');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the inputs are added dynamically, you need to use [`event delegation`](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to register the event handler

```
// New way (jQuery 1.7+) - .on(events, selector, handler)
$(document).on('focusout', 'input', function(event) {
    $(this).addClass('active'); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Where are you loading script.js ? Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( input ).focusout( function() {
      $( this ).addClass('active');
  });

  $( document ).on( "click", ".btn", function() {
      $('.edit-wrapper').load('index-edit.php');
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

need to use event delegation

```
$( document).on('focusout',  'input ', function() {
    $( this ).addClass('active');
});
```